# Why use IEventDispatcher.hasListener()?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash

I'm curious as to the performance benefits of using hasEventListener() over blindly dispatching an event?

For example, I see in the Flex framework code snippets such as the following:

```
// from ArrayList.setItemAt()
var hasCollectionListener:Boolean = hasEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE);
if (hasCollectionListener)
{
     dispatchEvent(new CollectionEvent(....))
}
```

I assume that this infers there are performance benefits of not dispatching the event if no-one is listening, versus blindly dispatching it, regardless of whether there are any listeners attached.

However, this doesn't seem to make sense.

Surely listeners are internally stored within some sort of performant hashmap.  I'd have thought that checking to see if a listener exists is roughly as performant as iterating through the empty array of listeners.

Therefore, why bother checking, and not just blindly invoke the `dispatchEvent` method? The original code sample is significantly clumsier than had they just dispatched the event.

Regards,

Marty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, running this check is redundant.  If nobody is listening, then there is nothing in the listeners collection, so `dispatchEvent` would be very quick... probably as quick as asking if there are any listeners... at least from a macro level.

I suppose a quick run through a profiler would tell us for sure... This type of pre-optimization only introduces more code and therefore introduces the chances of stoopid copy/paste bugs unless you know for sure that there is a pref **problem** here and that this helps relieve it.

There are some uses for the `hasEventListener` call, though.  Something like this would make sense:

```
if(hasEventListener("HeavyComputationChanged")) {
    doSomeHeavyComputation();
    dispatchEvent("HeavyComputationChanged");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly that check is not redundant. `dispatchEvent(new Event("foo"))` always creates a new object of type `Event` and dispatches it. It doesn't matter if there are listeners registered or not. See my answer for further information.

Comment: Functionally, it IS redundant.  This feels like a micro optimization to me... It's not like Event objects are terribly large... I try to avoid micro optimizations in favor of less code in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Dispatching events even though there are no event listeners registered can have an impact on your application's performance. So using `hasEventListener()` is considered best practice.

There's a long discussion going on on Adobe's bugtracker about this topic: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-24249

In a nutshell: When you write `dispatchEvent(new Event("foo"))` a new object of type `Event` gets created and the event gets dispatched. Eventually the GC comes and remoes the event object from memory. You wont notice any difference in situations where the event fires only a few times. In case of bindings or other events that get dispatched in a large number the usage of `hasEventListener()` can make a difference.

Since Flex 4 the code generated by the compiler when you use [Bindable] always uses `hasEventListener()` before dispatching an event.

Comment: Right. It's about memory consumption, not dispatch performance. The test to hasEventListener() is a way to avoid the cost of creating (and then collecting) an Event instance.

Answer (score 0):

Does the receiving method make a call to Event.stopPropagation() or Event.stopImmediatePropagation()?

I can see they would want to check if the event listener was there if they don't want it to bubble to other listeners in the application. If the listener wasn't there, it wouldn't be able to prevent the propagation until it messes something else up like another component of the same type!